# Event for DOM changed or hook when $ is called?

Tags: jquery, events, dom

I want to format currencies via JavaScript, so that i. e. "5.99" becomes "5,99 €". I thought I could do that by giving elements containing currencies a special class and using jQuery selectors to find those elements and format their content, something like:

```
<!-- ... -->
<td class="currency">5.99</td>
<!-- ... -->

// ...
$(".currency").each(function(index, element) {
    element.html( myNumberFormatMethod(element.text()) );
});
// ...
```

Putting the given JavaScript code into jQuery's onload method works fine for elements that already exist in the DOM tree when the page is received from the server. But I also need that function to be executed whenever an element with the given class is created dynamically. Unfortunately there is no event like "dom changed", so what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why don't just apply the same action after you create an element ?

Comment: How exactly is the element being changed

Comment: The elements are changed in different places so I would have to update the code everywhere I update the elements, that's why I want to detect when the element is changed/created

Answer (score 0):

When said elements are changed/added, trigger an event on them.

```
$("#sometable").append(newRowWithCurrency).find(".currency").trigger("changed");
```

now you can catch that with a delegated event handler and update the text.

```
$(document).on("changed",".currency",function(){
    $(this).html( myNumberFormatMethod($(this).text()) );
});
```

Comment: I ended up doing it this way, not exactly what I wanted but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

for the record, it is possible to check if elements are created in the dom. however browser support is not good (IE has problems with it).

I made a jsfiddle demonstrating [DOMNodeInserted](http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-how-to-use-the-domnodeinserted-event-and-why-its-important/)

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/AAd8f/1/ (might not work in IE)

Also, if the elements (new currency values) are added by an ajax-call you could also use $.ajaxSetup to define a standard callback function on success.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        // standard stuff that has to be done before every ajax call
    },
    complete: function(xhr, stat) {
        // standard stuff that has to be when complete
    }
    success: function(result,status,xhr) {
        // standard stuff that has to be done when success: in your case add currency symbols

    }
});
```

However your best option might be using callbacks in the dom node creation functions, like mentioned in the other answer.